# Restricting all the tables in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

In one of my application Hibernate is getting used and when i'm trying to fetch a single record based on the customerId, all the table as mapped in the hibernate config file is getting loaded and locally my application is timed out as there are huge data in the database table. Please suggest is there in way so that i can stop loading all the tables? Is there anything needs to be done in the hibernate config file?

Thanks,
Sourav

Comment: what exactly is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If a whole lot of rows are loaded when you retrieve a single row, it means that you configured a whole lot of associations to other entities to be eagerly loaded. Configure them as lazy-loaded, and they won't be loaded by default.